# Printing out to file each Game of life generations

Tags: c++, fstream, conways-game-of-life

Hey guys i need help with a fstream print out for each Game of life generations. Currently it is only printing out the initial grid with all dead cells.

Here is my print function, and what i attempted.

```
void print(bool mat[][Row]) //Prints matrix to screen
{
     ofstream myfile;
     myfile.open("GameOfLife.txt");
     cout << setw(3) << " ";
     myfile<< setw(3) << " ";
     for (int p = 0; 5*p < Row; p++) cout << setw(5) << 5*p+1;
     for (int p = 0; 5*p < Row; p++) myfile << setw(5) << 5*p+1;
     cout << endl;
     myfile<< endl;
     for (int m = 0; m < Col; m++)
     {
         cout << setw(3) << m+1;
         myfile<< setw(3) << m+1;
         for (int n = 0; n < Row; n++)
         {
             if (mat[m][n]) cout << "\xDB";
             else cout << /*"\xB1"*/"-";
             if (mat[m][n]) myfile << "\xDB";
             else myfile << /*"\xB1"*/"-";
         }
         cout << endl;
         myfile<<endl;
     }
}
```

Here is where i call it in main

```
 do //Keep updating new generations
    {
        cout<<"Generation: "<<genX<<endl;
        //myfile<<"Generation: "<<genX<<endl;
        genX++;
        clear(next);
        calculate(now, next);
        swap(now, next);
        print(now);
        cin>>cont;      
    }while(cont == -1);
```

Was wondering how i can get it to print each generation to the file.

edit:added whole code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#define Col 15 //Col size
#define Row 13 //Row size
using namespace std;

void clear(bool mat[][Row]) //resets with all dead cells
{
    for (int m = 0; m < Col; m++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < Row; n++)
            mat[m][n] = 0;
    }
}

void print(bool mat[][Row]) //Prints matrix to screen
{
     ofstream myfile;
     myfile.open("GameOfLife.txt");
     cout << setw(3) << " ";
     myfile<< setw(3) << " ";
     for (int p = 0; 5*p < Row; p++) cout << setw(5) << 5*p+1;
     for (int p = 0; 5*p < Row; p++) myfile << setw(5) << 5*p+1;
     cout << endl;
     myfile<< endl;
     for (int m = 0; m < Col; m++)
     {
         cout << setw(3) << m+1;
         myfile<< setw(3) << m+1;
         for (int n = 0; n < Row; n++)
         {
             if (mat[m][n]) cout << "\xDB";
             else cout << /*"\xB1"*/"-";
             if (mat[m][n]) myfile << "\xDB";
             else myfile << /*"\xB1"*/"-";
         }
         cout << endl;
         myfile<<endl;
     }
}

/*void print2(unsigned int mat[][Row]) //Prints matrix to screen
{
     for (int m = 0; m < Col; m++)
     {
         for (int n = 0; n < Row; n++)
             cout << mat[m][n] << " ";
         cout << endl;
     }
}*/

void calculate(bool mata[][Row], bool matb[][Row])
{
     unsigned int neighbors;
     for (int m = 0; m < Col; m++)
     {
         for (int n = 0; n < Row; n++)
         {
             neighbors = 0;
             //Begin counting number of neighbors:
             if (mata[m%Col-1][n%Row-1] == 1) neighbors += 1;
             if (mata[m%Col-1][n%Row] == 1) neighbors += 1;
             if (mata[m%Col-1][n%Row+1] == 1) neighbors += 1;
             if (mata[m%Col][n%Row-1] == 1) neighbors += 1;
             if (mata[m%Col][n%Row+1] == 1) neighbors += 1;
             if (mata[m%Col+1][n%Row-1] == 1) neighbors += 1;
             if (mata[m%Col+1][n%Row] == 1) neighbors += 1;
             if (mata[m%Col+1][n%Row+1] == 1) neighbors += 1;

             //Apply rules to the cell:
             if (mata[m%Col][n%Row] == 1 && neighbors < 2)
                matb[m%Col][n%Row] = 0;
             else if (mata[m%Col][n%Row] == 1 && neighbors > 3)
                matb[m%Col][n%Row] = 0;
             else if (mata[m%Col][n%Row] == 1 && (neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3))
                matb[m%Col][n%Row] = 1;
             else if (mata[m%Col][n%Row] == 0 && neighbors == 3)
                matb[m%Col][n%Row] = 1;
         }
     }
}

void swap(bool mata[][Row], bool matb[][Row]) //Replaces first matrix with second
{
     for (int m = 0; m < Col; m++)
     {
         for (int n = 0; n < Row; n++)
             mata[m%Col][n%Row] = matb[m%Col][n%Row];
     }
}


int main()
{
    bool now[Col][Row], next[Col][Row]; //Creates now and then matrixes
    int x, y, cont; //Used for user input

    cout << left << "Welcome to Conway's Game of Life." << endl << endl;
    cout << "The Rules of Life:" << endl;
    cout << "1.cell with less than 2 neighbors die" << endl;
    cout << "2. cell with more than three neighbors dies" << endl;
    cout << "3. cell with two or three neighbors lives stays alive." << endl;
    cout << "4.dead cell with exactly three live neighbors comes to life." << endl << endl;
    cout << "To play: Press any key to begin. Enter the column and row of a cell to make \nalive, separated by a space. ";
    cout << "enter 1 1 to fill grid with dead cells, enter \"-1\" to begin the \nsimulation. Then enter any number to continue or \"-1\" to move to next generation." << endl;
    cin.get();

    clear(now);
    print(now);

    do //Get initial state
    {
        cin >> x;
        if (x == -1) break; //User is done inputting
        cin >> y;
        now[y-1][x-1] = 1; //Sets cell to alive
        print(now); //Updates screen
    }while(x != -1);
    int genX=1;
    do //Keep updating new generations
    {
        cout<<"Generation: "<<genX<<endl;
        //myfile<<"Generation: "<<genX<<endl;
        genX++;
        clear(next);
        calculate(now, next);
        swap(now, next);
        print(now);
        cin>>cont;      
    }while(cont == -1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't remember off-hand, but I think the default for `open` is to truncate. You either want to open the file *once* at the start of the app and pass the `ofstream`, or use the "append" parameter (but you still would want to delete it or truncate it once for each run of the application).

Comment: added the whole code if it helps

Answer (score 2):

Every time you `open` a file, it is truncated, unless you open for appending.

Since you want to create a new file on each run but keep appending to it, the cleanest way is to pass the open file to the print method. Plus, it doesn't have to be a file, you can print to any `std::ostream`.
And, as an added bonus, all your duplication for printing to `cout` also disappears, and you can get rid of one output or the other by changing just one line in `main`.

```
void print(ostream& stream, bool mat[][Row]) //Prints matrix to stream
{
     stream << setw(3) << " ";
     for (int p = 0; 5*p < Row; p++) 
         stream << setw(5) << 5*p+1;
     stream << endl;
     for (int m = 0; m < Col; m++)
     {
         stream << setw(3) << m+1;
         for (int n = 0; n < Row; n++)
         {
             if (mat[m][n]) 
                 stream << "\xDB";
             else 
                 stream << "-";
         }
         myfile << endl;
     }
}
```

Here is how to use it in `main`

```
ofstream myfile("GameOfLife.txt");
do 
{
    // ... as before ...
    print(cout, now);     // Print to stdout
    print(myfile, now);   // print to the file
    cin >> cont;      
} while (cont == -1);
```

In order for anyone to figure out why your final generation is all dead, you would need to provide a sample first generation.